# SQL Inner Join Descrepancies: Greedy Match Last Instance

Tags: sql, inner-join, self-join

I'm stumped. I have a table that contains information on trips over the last few years for people in my organization. Our goal is to determine the time between any given trip that the person was home "DwellAC". The trips may not have been entered in order. I know I need to narrow down the trips and select the most recent trip before the current lines trip and then subtract the dates. Im trying to use a self join because all the data is in only one table. This is my attempt at the SQL to calculate the Dwell for each trip.

```
UPDATE Deployments AS d1 
INNER JOIN Deployments AS d2 
ON d1.AC=d2.AC or d1.AC=d2.FP 
SET d1.DwellAC = d1.DepartMcGuire-d2.ReturnMcGuire
WHERE d2.ReturnMcGuire<d1.DepartMcGuire And d1.AC<>'' And d1.ID<>d2.ID;
```

I thought the code was working just fine. It seemed to be calculating everything correctly. I started to run into trouble when new trips were added in the past. Meaning that we found new data to input an old trip. The index on the new-old trips is higher and seems to be throwing thing off.

I realized this morning that I obviously need to include more data. The table looks like this.

```
AC    DwellAC DepartMcGuire ReturnMcGuire
Evan          1/1/2011      2/1/2011
Evan          3/10/2011     4/10/2011
Evan          1/1/2010      6/1/2010
```

The goal is to properly fill the DwellAC column with the time home between trips.

Is there any way I could use a nested where query to find the max date < the next depart date to use in the update query?

I know the pseudo code would look like this

```
For each AC
Select all trips where oldtrip.returnMcGuire < thistrip.departMcGuire and AC=AC
From these trips select MAX oldtrip.ReturnMcGuire
Update this.DwellAC = maxfound oldtrip.returnMcguire - thistrip.departMcGuire
```

Thanks for any help, I am not sure if I even need the inner join anymore

Ive found this query

```
SELECT CurrentTrip.AC, CurrentTrip.DwellAC, CurrentTrip.FP, CurrentTrip.DepartMcGuire,    
(SELECT MAX(LastTrip.ReturnMcGuire)
 FROM Deployments AS LastTrip
 WHERE ((CurrentTrip.AC=LastTrip.AC OR CurrentTrip.AC=LastTrip.FP) AND (LastTrip.ReturnMcGuire<CurrentTrip.DepartMcGuire))) AS LastReturnMcGuire
 FROM Deployments AS CurrentTrip
```

Gives me the data I need in the forms of CurrentTrip.DepartMcGuire-LastReturnMcGuire
I just need to turn it into an update statement.

Perhaps something like this? which is not workin

```
UPDATE Deployments AS CurrentTrip
SET CurrentTrip.DwellAC = CurrentTrip.DepartMcGuire-(SELECT MAX(LastTrip.ReturnMcGuire) FROM Deployments AS LastTrip WHERE CurrentTrip.AC=LastTrip.AC);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `ORDER BY d1.DepartMcGuire` ?

Comment: "The index on the new-old trips is higher and seems to be throwing thing off." What? Do you mean the ID is higher?

Comment: The rows were added recently so their index is higher than previous rows, I know this shouldn't matter but when the trips are in chronological order in the database index it seems to be working fine

Comment: Its seems difficult to order by when using an update query?

Comment: Could you explain the fields in you query? It's hard to help if we have no idea what these fields represent? Perhaps post an example sample of what your current data looks like and what you want to do with it.